# Area of a Self-intersecting Curve

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, area

I was doing some work finding the areas of rose curves. The rose curve is a polar curve given by the equation

$$
r(\theta) = \cos{k\theta}
$$
When $k$ is even, the area is $\pi/2$, and when $k$ is odd, the area is $\pi/4$. But I got stuck when thinking about the area of the rose curve when $k$ is rational and not an integer. The petals formed by such a rose curve all overlap each other, so what part of the curve would be considered the *area*? Would the area be the entire area surrounded by the curve, or would it be only the "inner" parts of the curve?

Furthermore, if $k$ is irrational, then the rose will have infinitely many petals and thus have infinite length. This means that the curve forms a dense set on the unit disc. So would the area of this curve be $\infty$, or would it be the area of a circle that encloses the curve?

**EDIT:** Maybe a better generalization of the question is; what is defined as the area of a self-intersecting figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I_{even} = 2\pi / (\pi/k)\cdot \int_{-\pi/(2k)}^{\pi/(2k)} \cos^2(k\theta)/2\; d\theta = k\cdot [\theta/2+\sin(2k\theta)/4k] = k\cdot (\pi/(2k) + 0) = \pi/2$ for $k \in \mathbb{2Z}$. Also, note that $I_{odd} = 1/2\cdot I_{even} = \pi/4$ for $k$ odd. Note that the circle of radius $1$ contains this curve and so the area must be less than $\pi$. When $k$ is not an integer but rational, then the curve is not well-defined (think +$2\pi$). If irrational, then the curve is not closed, so how could the area even be defined?

Feel free to ask more questions if required.

Comment: Thanks for catching me on the fact that the area is actually $\pi/2$ when k is even and $\pi/4$ when odd. You have to differentiate between k even and odd because if you calculated the area using $1/2\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos^2{k\theta}d\theta}$ when k is odd, you would actually calculate $2$ times the area. How did you end up with your integral?

Comment: You are quite correct. There are half as many petals when $k$ is odd. I calculated it by multiplying number of petals by area inside. Yours is also valid.

Comment: hi. its been a while since ive done much integrating. but im using this calculation atm am confused where youve constructed the integral term and limits from. could you bear with me to add abit more detail? id be ever so obliged *pomme voice*